# How could I check if the value for A is on average higher/lower than B across all pairs containing A and B?

Tags: regression, inference, descriptive-statistics

I have a dataset with prices from big stores and small stores for the same product for different cities. My dataset has around 70 products and both big stores and small store prices are available for each product in most cities, but all cities (sometimes product A in City XYZ is only available in big stores).

What type of analysis could I run to examine whether big or small store prices are systematically (or on average) lower or higher across all products?

**EDIT** I forgot to add that price collecting is attempted for the same pairs of stores in each city. So price collection is attempted in big store 1 and small store 1 across all cities, then for big store 2 and small store 2 across all cities, big store 3 and small store 3 across all cities and so forth

Of course, sometimes prices are only available in, say, big store 5 in city XZY, while in city ZZZ they're available for both big store 5 and small store 5.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "systematically" and "an average"?  The former would seem to mean "for every store," but since that's so simple to check I figure you're trying to ask something else.  The latter is inscrutable--maybe there's a typo in this post?

Comment: @whuber. I'd like to make some statement along the lines of "products from big stores *generally* cost more/less than products from small stores". I hope this clears things up a bit. I clarified an additional aspect about my dataset above (unrelated to your concern, though)

Comment: How are the products chosen? How are the stores chosen and how do you decide whether they're large or small? Are you trying to make a statement about all stores or only the stores that you had data on?

Comment: How about an ANOVA design with blocks as cities?

Comment: @Glen_b all products are chosen from a predetermined list developed based on judgment. Once each product price is reported there is additional information collected that determines whether a store is big or small (not sure how they do this) -- I only see the "big store" or "small store" tag in my data (don't want to get into how they decide what's small or big). Regarding the statement I want to make, I'd like to make one ideally on ALL stores. But since not all stores had data, then something only on the stores that had data would suffice. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Glen_b my edit above may clarify things better. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user2974951 would this be equivalent to running the following regression with two dummy variables: *prices = dummy_bigstore + dummy_small store* (note: no intercept)

Comment: No it's not the same, also you should almost always include the intercept in a regression model.